# Php style show function

Tags: php, text, show

Hi guys I want that on click of the button "show" the following inputs became visible, can someone help me?

```
<input id="show"type="submit" value="change" >
<input id="oldpass"TYPE="text"value="" style="display: none">
<input id="newpass"TYPE="text"value="" style="display: none">
<input id="cambia"TYPE="submit"value="" style="display: none">
```

Comment: Read about **IF** statements. After you've done that, echo html in the if statement.

Comment: This can't be done with PHP. Try looking at a [javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) solution

Comment: It _could_ be done with PHP, but PHP is __server-side__, so it would involve sending a request to the server and reloading the entire page with a different visible element. Probably not what the OP wants. Remember that javascript is __client-site__, so behavior like this is almost always handled with javascript (in the browser).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
<input id="show" type="submit" name="submit" value="change" >
</form>

<?php 
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
       echo "<input id='oldpass' type='text' value=''>";
       echo "<input id='newpass' type='text' value='' >";
       echo "<input id='cambia' type='submit' value='' >";
    }
?>
```

you can use this one.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript/jQuery:

```
$('#show').click(function() {
    $('#oldpass').css("display", "block");
    $('#newpass').css("display", "block");
    $('#cambia').css("display", "block");
 });
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d68hr9oh/)

As Jon Surrell mentioned, PHP is server side, so this type of behaviour is almost always handled client side with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I made this fiddle for you using jQuery, if you don't understand the code check the docs at: http://api.jquery.com

The fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ujp7c67s/1/

You can't do this with PHP, because PHP is a server side programming language. For everything that you need to change *after* the page loaded look into client side programming like javascript (jQuery is a javascript library)

```
$('#show').on('click', function() {
    $('input', '.form-class').show();
});
```

Comment: Please edit the function's code as this would simply shall all inputs on the page... It would seems better to do a find on the parent node element (I believe jQuery it would be something like  $(this).find('input))

Comment: This is just to make the code clear to understand. It would actually be better to do it like $('input', 'container')

Comment: Well, I just mentioned that as the person dos not seem to really know much about javascript (considering his question) and it would be best to be a little more precise. Again, I a not downvoting or anything, just proposing a little more precision to help him ;)